# Is there a reason for dynamic variables to not be private?

Tags: php, oop, class, dynamic

It's possible to extend classes during runtime, and I've been playing around with it a bit, but then I stumbled upon this, which to me is strange. If I define a new variable in a private function it becomes a public variable. Shouldn't it at least be protected?

Here's the code that I've used to test this:

```
class FooBar {

public function FooBar() {
    $this->t();
}

public function createVariable() {
    $this->NewVar();
}

private function NewVar() {
    $this->iam = "Hello you!";
}

private function t() {
    $this->T = "ballad";
    return $this->T;
}

}

$fb = new FooBar();
echo $fb->T;
echo "<br/>";
var_dump($fb);
$fb->createVariable();
echo $fb->iam;
echo "<br/>";
var_dump($fb);
echo "<br/>";
$fb->outer = "okay";
echo $fb->outer;
```

And as an extra, since it's possible to extend a class during runtime why isn't this possible:

```
function foo() {
    private $this->anewvar = 0; //private is illegal.
}
```

Comment: Why should it? And regarding your second question: This is not even valid PHP...

Comment: I know it's not valid, thats the point. If I can extend my class during runtime, why can't I decide wether it should be public or not?

Comment: Your second example would require to change the parser, which seems quite unnecessary for such a minor issue. You should "do it right" instead `private $anewvar; function() { $this->anewvar = 0;}`. The property overloading is more a convinience feature to create dynamic mapped objects, for example when you map JSON on `stdClass`. This also explains, why it's public: It doesn't make sense to create mapped value-objects and then don't allow to access it ;) As mentioned: Create real classes for real cases and not patchwork. Beside: The still supported `var $foo;` creates public properties too ;)

Comment: Just to be clear I'm not promoting this, I'm sure it has its uses somehow, somewhere. But I haven't been in a situation yet where I've needed it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP allows variables to be instantiated at any time without explicitly defining them.

But since you haven't defined the variable explicitly, PHP doesn't know how you want it to be scoped, and it has no way for you to tell it either, so it just goes with the safest possible option and makes it public.

If you want it scoped privately, define it as a private variable in the class definition.

Comment: I thought that maybe if the variable is defined in a private function it would be private.